# CodeBlocks and OpenCV on Mac (Snow leopard)

Tags: opencv, linker, settings, codeblocks, directory

Me and my friend are trying to setup a CodeBlocks project on Mac with OpenCV 2.3.1. We have compiled the binaries (dylib and .a files) for the GNU GCC compiler.

We have the following settings:

Search directories:

- Compiler: OpenCV/Include (This is where opencv and opencv2 include .h files is)
- Linker: OpenCV/Lib (This is where the dylib and .a files is)

Linker settings:

- Link libraries: libopencv_calib3d_pch_dephelp.a, ... (All the .a files)

We keep getting the error: Symbol(s) not found,
at "cv::VideoCapture::isOpened() const" and a lot more places.

Anyone who knows if this is correct, or have a reference to a guide showing how to set this up?

Comment: Thank you for the reminder. I'm still learning how stackoverflow works, so it is nice of you to educate me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the [official tutorial](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/CodeBlocks)?

The tutorial describes how to configure it on Windows, but you'll have to do pretty much the same things under Mac OS X. The paths will certainly be different, but the overall procedure remains the same. Also, instead of `.lib` files you'll ne using `.dylib` files.